# How to update, delete sql values in sqlitedb android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I can create the db and access the values but the issue I am running into is updating the values associated with the identifier.  Essentially I have

```
 id    |  value
 |1|        1
 |2|        2
 |3|        3
```

I am looking for way to update the value of (id) 2 and so on.  Also how to delete the row as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below tutorial has everything what all you need, please go through

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Good one,

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html